# iText 7 - Out of Range Exception when calling PdfFormField.SetValue or PdfAcroForm.FlattenFields

Tags: asp.net-core, itext7

My employer is currently using Classic ASP and FDFs to load PDFs from a database, populate them, and serve them to the browser.  They'd like to create a more modern implementation matching their new ASP.NET Core paradigm, and so my attention was drawn to iText 7, which I'm given to understand has supported Core, at least experimentally, for a few versions now.  An example PDF that I'm trying to fill in is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10SMEHkh8jq1DOTpYclh_2tCErYjAHJCm).

The following is my current attempt. "doc" is an object containing the PDF as a byte array (doc.Document), along with the names of the fields to populate (doc.DocumentFields.DocFieldName), and the text with which I want to populate those fields (doc.DocumentFields.ReplacementText).

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(doc.Document));
MemoryStream ffoutput = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ffoutput);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, false);
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    string key = field.Key;
    PdfFormField varField = form.GetField(key);
    DocField keyField = doc.DocumentFields.Where(p => p.DocFieldName == key).FirstOrDefault();
    if (keyField != null)
    {
        varField.SetValue(keyField.ReplacementText);
    }   
 }

 form.FlattenFields();
 pdfDoc.Close();
 doc.Document = ffoutput.ToArray();
```

Running this gives me the following exception on the line where I call varField.SetValue():

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRange_IndexException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfArray.Get(Int32 index, Boolean asDirect)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfArray.GetAsNumber(Int32 index)
   at iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.DrawBorder(PdfCanvas canvas, PdfFormXObject xObject, Single width, Single height)
   at iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.DrawTextAppearance(Rectangle rect, PdfFont font, Single fontSize, String value, PdfFormXObject appearance)
   at iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.RegenerateField()
   at iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField.SetValue(String value, Boolean generateAppearance)
```

Noting that this is stemming from drawing the field's appearance, I passed "false" into SetValue's optional GenerateAppearance parameter and thereafter that error went away.  However the same error then popped up on form.FlattenFields().  So I saw that it's possible to disable generating appearances in FlattenFields() using PdfAcroForm.SetGenerateAppearance(false), and I tried that.  This eliminated the error entirely, however the resulting PDF contained only blank fields, minus the couple of fields with default values set.

In this last scenario, I am able to set a breakpoint and add a watch on varField.GetValue() after SetValue() is called, and see that the value is ostensibly set to the text I'm after.  I assume, therefore, that if I were able to let the methods I'm using generate appearances the way they want to, that I'd likely see my values.

I've scoured Stack Overflow for an answer, gone through dozens of questions.  The only [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49033666/index-out-of-bounds-exception-with-itext-7-setvalue) I could find, which seemed to match my issue *precisely* from what I can see on Google, was deleted.

Is this an issue stemming from the "experimental" nature of the software's support for .Net Standard/Core?  Or am I doing something really dumb?  Thanks for your time.

EDIT: I should also mention that I tried the default pattern mentioned in the tutorials and got the same result.  By this I mean:

```
fields.TryGetValue(field, out toSet);
toSet.SetValue("0");
```